How to show/log all commits (and only those) from stdin?
I have a list of commits and I want git-log(1) or git-show(1) to show all of them. But
only them. Not also commits that are reachable from them.

git-log(1)
You need --stdin which lets you provide options and commits from
standard in as well as the one you’ve already provided.  Keep in mind
that it seems that this should be the last argument that you provide.
Then you need --no-walk which stops the command from finding
ancestors.
$ cat example.txt
HEAD
HEAD~2
HEAD~5
$ <example.txt git log --no-walk --stdin

Example application:
ref=commits
[ "$(git notes --ref="$ref" | head -1)" ] \
    && git notes --ref="$ref" list \
    | cut -d' ' -f 2 \
    | git log --no-walk --ignore-missing --stdin

git-show(1)
(Thanks to eftshift0)
git-show(1) will let you both show commits and other kinds of objects
(the example application takes objects from Git Notes and Notes can be
attached to any object).
$ cat example.txt
HEAD
HEAD~2
HEAD~5
<example.txt git show --stdin

The example application:
ref=commits
[ "$(git notes --ref="$ref" | head -1)" ] \
    && git notes --ref="$ref" list \
    | cut -d' ' -f 2 \
    | git show --ignore-missing --stdin


I wonder if git show is more like what you want instead of using all those log options.

@eftshift0 I don’t personally need git-show(1). But I can expand the QA to both commands. Thanks.
